# unit testing of subscribe

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a component which has a get call on ngOninit

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setMemberRoles();
  }

  public setMemberRoles(): void {
    this.teamService.getMemberRoles().subscribe((response: ICreatedByRole) => {
      this.memberRoles = response;
    });
  }
```

I want to write test cases pf this:

```
it('should set member roles in variable member roles', async(() => {
    let response: ICreatedByRole[] = [];

    spyOn(teamServiceStub, 'getMemberRoles').and.returnValue(of(response));
    component.setMemberRoles();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.memberRoles).toEqual(response);
  }));
```

I have tried this, but it throws error

```
 <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for getMemberRoles()
    Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Mock the teamService.

```
class MockTeamService {

 getMemberRoles {
  return 'fake response'
   }
}
```

Inject this MockTeamService in providers as.

```
{provider: TeamService, useClass: MockTeamService}
```

Get the injected service.

```
teamService = TestBed.get(TeamService);
```

Then SpyOn:

```
const memberSpy = spyOn(teamService, 
'getMemberRoles').and.returnValue(of(response));
```